# Android In App Purchases: can user buy multiple copies of same product at once

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am interested, if user of In App Billing Android app can buy multiple copies of the same in app product with one click of " Buy " button. For example, if the product is " Gold coin ", can we buy 2 coins at once? Or we need to process buy flow twice?

Comment: Logic would be "one at a time" as it could lead the user to buy too much if he had to chose how many items.

Comment: Why not offering "2 x Gold coin" item?

Comment: Thank You for Your response, @xoxel. Now it is clear for me. :)

Comment: Ok, @B001ᛦ, I've think about it. I just want to know, is it possible to mention, for example, amount of copies of the same product,and buy it at once. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot buy two items at once from google in App Purchases, its not supported. You can however bundle those multiple items and present it as a single item. Like make a bundle of 2x Coins